# AWS opswork-agent not starting

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, aws-opsworks

I am trying to start opswork-agent on aws instance with following command,

`sudo service opsworks-agent start`

But it is failing with following error,

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:34:in `singleton class': undefined method `default_specifications_dir' for class `#<Class:Gem::Specification>' (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:1264:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:1264:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

Additional details:

ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [x86_64-linux]

gem version: 2.6.7

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following things.

1. If you launch an instance not through aws opsworks, kindly install the opsworks-agent in your ec2 instances.
2. If you launch an instance in aws opsworks console, you need to configure the layer to install opsworks-agent in an ec2 instance. When instance starts running, opsworks will start the opsworks-agent automatically from the instance.

DevOps Engineers not necessary to start the opsworks-agent manually from the instance.